# Are the subtitles of this video from an arabian tv program accurate with what the man is telling?

Tags: islam

It looks hard to believe for anyone who cares about his life that anyone can be saying all things that one of the persons in the video is telling about islam in a country where islam is highly extended. But it could be the case of a brave man, a very brave one indeed.

This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_4ZWpw0BFQ) I'm talking about.

I am skeptical that the subtitles match with what the man is really saying. I believe the man may be saying something different to the subtitles which would make this fake.

Can anyone confirm that the subtitles match with what the man is saying?

Comment: All you're likely to get here is someone who speaks that man's language and English either saying "Yes it matches the subtitles" or "No it doesn't". In either case, now you need to believe that person! That would be a bad answer here anyway, so what we would be after is some independent verification, or indeed the person themselves accepting or refuting the claim. I'm skeptical that we will get a decent answer to this question, but lets see!

Comment: Looks like a promotional video for the book

Comment: Even if someone could prove the subtitles are correct, all it proves is that someone read the book and got very upset and angrily yelled out the book's assertions, or that an actor was willing to portray that situation.

Answer (score 5):

Referring to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/arab-guy-renouncing-faith-television/), this claim is false since the original video showed activist Ihab al-Khouli reacting angrily to a speech by former Egyptian President Mohamed Morsi. The original transcript is found [here](http://www.memri.org/clip_transcript/en/3896.htm).